# How To group by date without time sql C#

Tags: c#, sql

Hi when i trying to select the date I get also the time, but I need to do group by date without the time.

I also tried this: `GROUP BY CAST(Orders.DatePlacing AS DATE)`, and I tried `Convert , DATE(Orders.DatePlacing)` and I tried this its not working for me.

Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0

```
public Product[] ProfitPrice(DateTime minDate, DateTime maxDate)
{
    maxDate=maxDate.AddDays(1);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ArrayList products = new ArrayList();

    string cmdStr = "SELECT Sum(((Products.PriceSell - Products.Price) * OrdersDetails.ProductCount)) AS Expr1,Orders.DatePlacing FROM Products " +
        "INNER JOIN(Orders INNER JOIN OrdersDetails ON Orders.OrderId = OrdersDetails.OrderId) " +
        "ON Products.ProductID = OrdersDetails.ProductId WHERE [Orders.DatePlacing] BETWEEN #" + minDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "#" + "AND" +
        " #" + maxDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "# "+
        "GROUP BY Orders.DatePlacing";

    using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(cmdStr))
    {
        ds = GetMultipleQuery(command);
    }
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    try
    {
        dt = ds.Tables[0];
    }
    catch { }

    foreach (DataRow tProduct in dt.Rows)
    {
        StatisticsFillArray(tProduct, products);
    }
    return (Product[])products.ToArray(typeof(Product));
}

private void StatisticsFillArray(DataRow tProduct, ArrayList products)
{
    Product productsData = new Product();
    productsData.PriceTotal = Convert.ToDouble(tProduct[0].ToString());
    productsData.EntryDate = tProduct[1].ToString();
    products.Add(productsData);
}
```

Comment: SQL Server, right?

Comment: Your code is sql injection vulnerable. Please, use command parameters, instead of concatenated string!

Comment: @RobertHarvey, seems it is an MS Access database.

Comment: It might be.  It also might be a linked-table SQL Server database.

Comment: Yes!! MS Access database

Comment: If you have a DateTime object in c# then use the property date.Date which truncates the data to midnight at the beginning of the day.  Try : ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<DateTime>("DatePlacing").Date)

Comment: @jdweng yes i have How can i do this in group by??

Comment: I just updated my last posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accordingly to my comment to the question...

1. your code is [sql injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/sql-injection?view=sql-server-ver15) vulnerable!
2. Do NOT use concatenated string, use [parameterized queries](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2017/07/01/parameterized-queries.aspx) instead.
3. Use table/column aliases!
4. To reject time part from datetime column, use [DateSerial function](https://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/dateserial.php)

How? Take a look at below code:

```
    string sql = @"SELECT Sum(((p.PriceSell - p.Price) * od.ProductCount)) AS Expr1, DateSerial(Year(o.DatePlacing), Month(o.DatePlacing), Day(o.DatePlacing)) DatePlacing 
    FROM Products p
    INNER JOIN(Orders o INNER JOIN OrdersDetails od
        ON o.OrderId = od.OrderId) 
            ON p.ProductID = od.ProductId
    WHERE DateSerial(Year(o.DatePlacing), Month(o.DatePlacing), Day(o.DatePlacing)) BETWEEN @mindate AND @maxdate
    GROUP BY DateSerial(Year(o.DatePlacing), Month(o.DatePlacing), Day(o.DatePlacing))";

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    using (OleDbConnection oConn = new OleDbConnection(yourConnectionStringHere))
    {
        oConn.Open();
        using (OleDbCommand oComm  = new OleDbCommand(yourCommandHere, oConn))
        {
                oComm.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(){"@mindate", OleDbType = OleDbType.Date, Value = minDate},);
                oComm.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(){"@maxdate", OleDbType = OleDbType.Date, Value = maxDate},);
            using (OleDbDataReader oRdr = oComm.ExecuteReader())
                dt.Load(oRdr);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're very welcome. Can you accept my answer as a solution?

Comment: How can i do that

Comment: Please, read this: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)